# How to use broadcast receiver to send data between fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have an app which has two fragments (1 and 2), and each has a Button.

In the 1st fragment I have an int variable which needs to get sent to fragment 2 using a broadcast receiver.

Then in fragment 2, there is another button which needs to display the data received.

Being a novice dev, if anyone has any help with this, it has been driving me crazy!

**Fragment1.java:**

```
package com.example.practiceapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

int someData;
Button frag1Btn;

public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);

    someData = 10;

    frag1Btn = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_1_btn);
    frag1Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //Broadcast receiver needs to fire from here
        }
    });

    return view;

    }

}
```

**Fragment2.java** (This is just empty for now)

```
package com.example.practiceapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

int dataFromFrag1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_2, container, false);


    return view;
}



}
```

Comment: Rather then Using broadcast receiver use ShareViewModel Instead.

Comment: use localbroadcast receivers

Comment: If you are using MVVM pattern, it would easy for you to use SharedViewModel. 
If not, you can use Callbacks much easier.

Comment: Anyone have any code examples for this?